# Dynamically dropping grid columns - effect on postbacks

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, datagrid, postback

I have read a number of threads here on the subject of posting back data from dynamically added datagrid columns. Everything I've read says that since the columns were added after the Init phase, they are not available in the control collection upon Postback and therefore any data posted back by these dynamically added columns is not available and cannot be restored from ViewState unless they are re-created in Page_Init. I have read that as long as the controls are re-added with identical IDS ( i.e IDS should match match posted back control ids), they will be restored from ViewState.

What if I'm not dynamically adding grid columns but rather dropping some grid columns in the code behind. So the ID's of the columns that remmin should match what was in the control collection to begin with so any data posted back should be resotored right but this is not what I'm seeing.  SUppos the following is the list of columns in my ASPX page. If in my code behind I drop the "Test" column but check the checkbox in the first column. Upon postback, the checkbox selection is not maintained. I would have expected it to based on what I've read. Can someone correct my understanding on this?

```
<Columns>
               <asp:TemplateColumn headertext="" headerstyle-width="1%" itemstyle-horizontalalign="center" FooterStyle-CssClass="DataGridFooter" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <input id="checkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAllDataGridCheckBoxes('checkboxIsSelected',this.checked)"/>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="checkboxIsSelected" checked='false' />
                    </itemtemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Subject" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" Visible="TRUE" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-CssClass="DataGridFooter" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="labelSubjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubjectID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Test"  HeaderStyle-Width="5%" Visible="TRUE" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-CssClass="DataGridFooter" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="labelTestCode" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TestCode") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>             
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Added BindGrid() and the event handler buttonApprove_click. The method SetGridColumns is the one that drops grid columns. Have included that too.

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            SetMasterDetailControlStates(IsPageInDetailsMode());

            if (!ValidateArgs())
            {
                gridBias.Visible = false;
                return;
            }

            foreach (ListItem displayOption in chkboxDisplay.Items)
            {
                if (displayOption.Selected)
                {
                    if (displayOption.Value == "Highlight") { _showHighlighting = true; }
                }
            }

            /*
              <Snipped>...Make procedure call to get dataset
            */

            DataSet ds = sp.GetDataSet();

            if (sp.RC != (int)ReturnCode.SUCCESS)
            {
                if ((sp.RC == (int)ReturnCode.NO_RECORDS_RETURNED))
                {
                    labelMessage.Text = "No data found for the specified filter";
                }
                else if ((sp.RC == (int)ReturnCode.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION) || (ds == null))
                {
                    labelMessage.Text = sp.ErrorMessage;
                }
                ds = null;
                gridBias.DataSource = ds;
                EnableControls(false);
                SetGridColumns();
            }
            else
            {
                gridBias.TitleText = BuildGridTitleString();
                gridBias.FilterText = BuildGridFilterString();
                gridBias.EnableRowsPerPageEdit = true;
                SetGridColumns();

                //Since grid columns are dynamically added and can change between postbacks
                //make sure sort column is valid, if not unset
                if (gridBias.SortColumn != null && gridBias.SortColumn.Length > 0)
                {
                    bool foundCol = false;
                    foreach (DataGridColumn dg in gridBias.Columns)
                    {
                        if (gridBias.SortColumn == dg.SortExpression)
                        {
                            foundCol = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!foundCol)
                    {
                        gridBias.SortColumn = "";
                        gridBias.SortOrder = "";
                    }
                }

                if (gridBias.SortColumn.Length == 0) gridBias.SortColumn = "TestCode";
                if (gridBias.SortOrder.Length == 0) gridBias.SortOrder = "ASC";
                if (gridBias.PageIndex.Length != 0 &&
                            !gridBias.GridViewMode.Equals(CustomDataGrid.GridViewType.SHOWALL.ToString()))
                    gridBias.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(gridBias.PageIndex);
                ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = gridBias.SortColumn + " " + gridBias.SortOrder;
                gridBias.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                EnableControls(true);
            }
            gridBias.HideEmptyColumns = true;
            ArrayList cols = new ArrayList();
            cols.AddRange(_alRecheckColumns);
            gridBias.HideEmptyColumnsList = cols;
            gridBias.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CodeLibrary.ErrorHandling.SetLabel("Error(" + CodeLibrary.ErrorHandling.GetMethodName() + ")", ex.Message, labelMessage, true, "ErrorMsg");
        }
    }

    private void SetGridColumns()
    {
        ArrayList alCols = new ArrayList();
        alCols.Add(""); //Checkbox column
        alCols.Add("Subject");

        ArrayList alColumnsToBeDeleted = new ArrayList();
        Boolean boolColExists = false;
        foreach (ListItem chart in chkboxChartType.Items)
        {
            if (chart.Value == "%Bias")                 
            {
                if (rblBiasOptions.SelectedValue == "Subject")
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn dg in gridBias.Columns)
                    {
                        boolColExists = false;
                        foreach (string gridColumn in alCols)
                        {
                            if (dg.HeaderText == gridColumn)
                            {
                                boolColExists = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!boolColExists)
                        {
                            alColumnsToBeDeleted.Add(gridBias.Columns.IndexOf(dg));
                        }                        
                    }
                }
           }
        // Loop thru the array list and delete columns from the grid.
        int count = 0;
        foreach (int i in alColumnsToBeDeleted)
        {
            gridBias.Columns.RemoveAt(i - count); //Subtract index by columns already     deleted.
            count++;
        }

    }

protected void buttonApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CheckPermission(this.ModuleId, this.GetType().BaseType.ToString(), "buttonApprove_Click");
            foreach (DataGridItem i in gridBias.Items)
            {
                //Loop thru each row and determien values to be saved to DB
                if (i.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || i.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    bool cbSelected = ((CheckBox)i.FindControl("checkboxIsSelected")).Checked;

                    if (cbSelected)
                    {
                        bool IsApproved = true;
                        string strSubjectID = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)i.FindControl("labelSubjectID")).Text;
                        string strTestCode = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)i.FindControl("labelTestCode")).Text;
                        string strSampleType = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)i.FindControl("labelSampleType")).Text;
                        string strTestCodeAndType = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)i.FindControl("labelTestCodeAndType")).Text;
                        if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)i.FindControl("labelRecheckNeedsApproval")).Text == "1")
                            IsApproved = true;
                        else
                            IsApproved = false;

                        SaveToDB(strSubjectID, strTestCode, strSampleType, strTestCodeAndType,IsApproved);
                    }
                }
            }

            BindGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObject)
        {
            string strExceptionMessage = exceptionObject.Message + "-" + exceptionObject.InnerException.Message;
            CodeLibrary.ErrorHandling.SetLabel("", strExceptionMessage, labelMessage, false, "ErrorMsg");   //--- Set label text
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, I am not rebinding on postback. The event handler ( for a button click ) is where control is transferred to and no binding occurs here. I would post the code but it is real wordy and might drown out my question. Do you still want me to?

Comment: @drdeadpan- sorry for my late response. I have checked your code with a DataGrid in the markup and believe that they are ok (in postback checkbox values were present in my test). In your situation I would check if viewstate is disabled. This post may help:[dropdownlist selectedvalue disapperaing on Submit (not IsPostBack issue!)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19015258/690329).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did check that before I posted and the datagrid has EnableViewState = True.

Comment: Did you also check page, masterpage and web.config?

Comment: Yes. I have a number of other controls on the page which make use of viewstate too and theu all work fine. If I make the grid static and adjust the visibility, the checkbox values are preserved. But if I drop columns, for some reason they are not.

Comment: That's a very generous offer but I'm afraid that will not be possible on account some company policy/confidentiality issues. I do appreciate. You said that you confirmed that if you drop the third column in your code behind, and check the check box and click a button, the checkbox selections are posted?

Comment: I understand... i will check again and let you know.

Comment: Even dropping 3rd column does not make any change. BTW, I had to remark many lines. I can't understand how can you have "TitleText", "FilterText" etc for a datagrid! Are you sure you are using this datagrid: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx)?

Comment: We are using a customized data grid. TitleText and FilterText are properties that are used to populate the Caption property of a basic data grid. I guess I really dont know then why things dont work for me. Willkeep you posted.

Comment: Probably it is a bug in your control. you can replace the control with standard control to test it.

Comment: I doubt it since the control is in use for many years now. Static columns yield issues at all. I will look into it further. Thanks