# dropdownlist selectedvalue disapperaing on Submit (not IsPostBack issue!)

Tags: asp.net, combobox

I have a DropDownList of states getting populated when the page initially gets loaded (ddl_state). I select a state, then click the Submit button. I have a breakpoint on the first line of the btn_submit_Click method. The Page_Load method is not getting run prior to this. On the first line of the btn_submit_Click method, the value of ddl_state.SelectedValue is an empty string. I tried setting AutoPostBack of the dropdownlist to true (read this somewhere and thought it might make a difference), but then the values in the dropdownlist just get cleared immediately!

Any ideas?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_state" runat="server" 
                                        meta:resourcekey="ddl_stateResource1">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) return;

        lbl_errors.Text = string.Empty;
        lblVoucherRequired.Text = string.Empty;

        tb_name_addr_1.Focus();
        PopulateStates();
        PopulateFormFromSessionData();
    }

protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ValidateInput()) // ddl_state.SelectedValue is an empty string here!!!
        {
            return;
        }

        SetSessionVariables();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `ViewState` is disabled.

This is indicative of both of your symptoms:

- `DropDownList` clears after postback with `AutoPostBack` is enabled
- Server does not know what the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList` is

Check the web.config, page, and control to check that none of them are disabling viewstate.

[DISABLE VIEWSTATE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1896566.aspx)